# Partial View not getting executed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Partial View that returns a table which is inserted in the DOM using Ajax.BeginForm(). But the Partial View is not getting called. When I step through the debugger, it just steps over the Partial View. Why?

---------------  This is the View with the Ajax call ----------------------

```
<h2>Enter a street name</h2> 

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("QuickSearchResults", "Search",
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            HttpMethod = "Get",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            UpdateTargetId = "test"
                        }))

{
     <input type="text" name="q" />
     <input type="submit" value="Search" />    
}   





<div id="test">

   </div>
```

----------------------Controller Action ----------------------------------

```
   public PartialViewResult QuickSearchResults(string q)
             {
                ViewBag.LogOn = true;
                var properties = remsrepository.GetPropertyByStreetName(q);

                **return PartialView("_Property", properties);**
             }

 ------------------------------Partial View --------------------------



@model IEnumerable<REMS.Models.Property>

   <table id="searchresults">
       <tr>
          <th>Adress</th>
          <th>Status</th>
       <th>List Price</th>
      </tr>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>


             <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.Property_Address.Street__ + " " +    `item.Property_Address.Street_Name,` 
                "PropertyDetails","Search", new {MLS = item.MLS})

            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Status
            </td>        
            <td>
                @item.List_Price
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

   </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `UpdateTargetId="searchresults"` but the `searchresults` element is qctually inside the partial view. This means that if the partial view is not part of the DOM when the page is initially loaded, when you submit the AJAX form there is no element with id="searchresults" yet, so nothing happens. One possibility is to put a div with an unique id outside the partial and then use it as `UpdateTargetId`.

Comment: I do have a table tag after the Ajax.BeginForm(). It didn't show up due to formatting issues. But you can see it now.  The Partial View does return a non-null object (Properties). But it is not getting inserted into the DOM. I also have a reference to script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript" in the _Layout.cshtml

Comment: @stackuser, ah, so you have 2 elements with the same id? That's invalid HTML.

Comment: Thank you! I removed table tag and added a div with a different name and it works. Thanks again.